# field validation to make dependency in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 fields - type(hw/sw),hardware type(dropdown) and asset_request.'Type' field is dropdown hardware(1) and software(2).'hardware type' has phone(1),camera(2),others(3)

If I chosen hardware(1),hardware type field is mandary and asset_request field is not mandatory.

If I chosen software(0) only asset_request field is mandatory.

If I chosen type=hardware(1) and hardware type=others(3) asset_request field is mandatory.
how to validate this in laravel

```
$this->validate($request,[
                'hardware_type' => 'required_without:asset_request',
                'asset_request' => 'required_without:hardware_type',
                 //want to check asset_request is required if hardware_type is 3 
            ],$messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'asset_request' => 'required_without:hardware_type',
```

change to

```
'asset_request' => 'required_without:hardware_type|required_if:hardware_type,==,3',
```

Doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

```
required_if:anotherfield,value,...
```

The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.